# Accelerometer whipping motion

Tags: java, accelerometer

**I just wanted some clarification on how to go about this.** 
I am creating an app that on different states such as the phone being whipped in the air and how to test for this.
For example if the user held the phone up and flicked it like a whip would I have to test.

- Once during the fast velocity of the flick.

Or

- Multiple times over the flick and when it comes to the stop at the end of the flick to make sure that I knew this action was a whipping one?

Comment: Test many different possibilities and discover what works the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that a good quick-and-dirty approach your problem is to:

1. Create an simple app which will read the x, y, and z values of the phone's accelerometer and save them to a CSV file.
2. Transfer that file on to your development computer, create a scatter plot, and look for patterns that indicate a whipping motion.
3. Use those patterns in your final app.

Keep in mind that the sampling rate that you use will affect the noise of the signal and drain on the battery. Also, remember that accelerometers measure acceleration, not velocity.

Comment: Can I just ask when I have found the trend, will the creation of the mathematical formulas be quite hard in terms of maths?

Comment: @alexczernenk That is hard for me to say. If math is "hard" is a matter of opinion. I would assume that a "whipping" motion will have a pronounced forward and backward motion, so the math may just looking for your readings to break certain thresholds. If you have difficulty with the math, then either post another question here or in the [math section of stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) with your data.